# Android build failures happening since 4th Nov 2022

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-studio, build.gradle

**The build error looks something like this:**

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Project'.
  Could not determine the dependencies of null.
  Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.

  > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
  > Required by:
  > project :
  > No matching variant of com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0 was found.
  > The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11,
  > packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well
  > as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.3.3'

Answer (score 3):

update this below content in project level build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
       exclusiveContent {
           filter {
               includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
           }
           forRepository {
               maven {
                   url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
               }
           }
       }
        // ...
    }
}
```

it's working for me

Answer (score 0):

**FIX INSIDE**

**Steps to resolve the react-native issue that we are facing since couple of days.**

1. Goto package.json and upgrade the react-native version to 0.64.4.(or whatever the supported version we have on the GitHub thread)
2. Run yarn install.
3. Now cd android
4. ./gradlew clean
5. cd ..
6. yarn android (now your project will execute properly)

Note: **This issue occurred because of the new release of the react native(4th nov), here I'm attaching the link for the reference.**

**URL : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210**

(if you face any issues do let me know i'll help you in resolving the same.)

Answer (score 0):

**This fix works:**

**Reason for Failures** : The build failures for Android was due to the publish of the React Native version 0.71.0-rc0 to Maven and because of which when the gradle is syncing its picking this 0.71.0-rc0 version of react-native rather then your current version of react-native.

Made it work without upgrading react-native version and by adding this in build.gradle, this works **(hermes enabled or not, along with flipper too)**

```
 exclusiveContent {
            // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
            // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
            // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
            // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
            filter {
                includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
            forRepository {
                maven {
                    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                }
            }
        }
```

final snippet looks like this

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        exclusiveContent {
            // We get React Native's Android binaries exclusively through npm,
            // from a local Maven repo inside node_modules/react-native/.
            // (The use of exclusiveContent prevents looking elsewhere like Maven Central
            // and potentially getting a wrong version.)
            filter {
                includeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
            forRepository {
                maven {
                    url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
                }
            }
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
```

gradle clean and rebuild after this fix. Then you can react native run android successfully.

What this fix will do is apply an `exclusiveContent` resolution rule that will force the resolution of React Native Android library, to use the one inside `node_modules`

If you dont want to put this fix, you can update your react native version for the project to the react native patch version as mentioned here

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210